# Navigation nested push caused by tabbar touch

Tags: ios, tabbarcontroller

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:      (UIViewController *)viewController{
    if (viewController == _personalNavViewCtrl) {
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    if (delegate.uid == nil) {//账户没有登陆过
         if (_loginViewCtrl == nil) {
            _loginViewCtrl = [[LoginViewCtrl alloc] init];
        }
        NSLog(@"_personalNavViewCtrl.ViewCtrl:%@",_personalNavViewCtrl.viewControllers);
        if (_personalNavViewCtrl.topViewController != _loginViewCtrl) {
            [_personalNavViewCtrl pushViewController:_loginViewCtrl animated:NO];
        }   
    }
 }
}
```

The above is the key code.the code have a `UITabBarController`, a `UINavigationController` is in it, its item is 4. When I touch item4, I want to push another `UIViewController` via some juge. So when the current item is 3, when i touch item4, it is ok. But when the current item is 4, i touch item4 again, I found this question. I find the `UINavigationController` `viewControllers` is only the rootViewController, the one I have pushed is dismissed.Another:the log tell me:1, nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar 2, Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. `NavigationBar` subview tree might get corrupted.

I do not know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

METHOD 1:

Use

```
- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent
                     animated:(BOOL)flag
                   completion:(void (^)(void))completion
```

to present your `_loginViewCtrl`

METHOD 2:

Test whether logined in

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController
shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

Comment: thank you ,but I want to know why the problem  happens